# Crystal Report to SSRS

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

I have this expression in crystal report

```
stringVar X :=   Right ({Database.Column},3);
Left (x,2)
```

I need to convert the above expression to SSRS Expression. Please, could anyone help on this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(Fields!DatabaseColumn.Value,3),2)
```

Example:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT("XXAB0",3),2)
```

It returns:

```
AB
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: @swan , If my answer helped you, you can select it as correct by clicking on the "correct" symbol at left of my answer. [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)